# TF Lite object detection only returning 10 detections

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using a custom object detection model with TensorFlow Lite on native Android. At this point I'm only detecting 2 custom objects. I am using the TensorFlow Object Detection API, and I have a pipeline in place that produces optimized .tflite files.

However, at inference time, the model only returns up to 10 individual detections. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview, this is expected. The problem is that my images have a relatively large object density. I need to be able to detect up to 30 individual objects per image/inference call.

If I change NUM_DETECTIONS in the sample Android app from the TF repo from 10 to, say, 20, I get a runtime exception due to shape mismatch. How can I produce .tflite files capable of yielding more than 10 object detection instances?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, since TFLite prefers static-shaped Input/Outputs, you would need to re-export a TFLite SSD graph with the required number of outputs. Instructions are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md). While invoking `object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py`, you would need to pass in the parameter `--max_detections=20`. Then, your change of `NUM_DETECTIONS` should work as expected.